# UFW not blocking connection

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I am using the Cloudflare [IPv4](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4) and [IPv6](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6) lists to block all connections to my server from any IP that is not owned by Cloudflare.

When I run `sudo ufw status` on the server I get:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       173.245.48.0/20            # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       103.21.244.0/22            # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       103.22.200.0/22            # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       103.31.4.0/22              # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       141.101.64.0/18            # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       108.162.192.0/18           # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       190.93.240.0/20            # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       188.114.96.0/20            # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       197.234.240.0/22           # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       198.41.128.0/17            # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       162.158.0.0/15             # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       104.16.0.0/13              # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       104.24.0.0/14              # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       172.64.0.0/13              # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       131.0.72.0/22              # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       2400:cb00::/32             # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       2606:4700::/32             # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       2803:f800::/32             # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       2405:b500::/32             # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       2405:8100::/32             # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       2a06:98c0::/29             # Cloudflare IP
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       2c0f:f248::/32             # Cloudflare IP
```

But when I run `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80` from my local machine (being xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx the IP of the server) I get:

```
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
```

So, looks like I am not getting blocked, when I should have been blocked as my local IP is not listed. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

I deployed another server just to do the same test and ensure that my IP is not white-listed. The result was the same.

**UPDATE 2:**

If I do `tracepath xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` I get something similar to this (IPs and domains censured):

```
1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1472
 1:  <MyComputerName>.mshome.net                           0.576ms
 1:  <MyComputerName>.mshome.net                           0.365ms
 2:  10.0.0.1                                              0.790ms
 3:  my.isp.provider.com                                   8.934ms
 4:  <My.Public.IP.Address>                                9.595ms asymm  5
 5:  no reply
 6:  an.isp.that.i.dont.know.com                          33.937ms
 7:  same.isp.that.i.dont.know.com                        46.866ms asymm  6
 8:  the.isp.that.i.dont.know.com                         45.673ms asymm  5
 9:  <IP.Owned.By.Cloud.My.Provider>                      42.138ms asymm  7
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1472
     Resume: pmtu 1472
```

Comment: Can you type `ufw status verbose` ? You should have one of the lines : `Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)`.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer This is how it looks in my server: `Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)`

Comment: Could you do `tracepath` for the server which you are trying to isolate?  It maybe that you are connecting through a server which has the IP range allowed.

Comment: @tukan Updated the threat with the result of `tracepath`

Comment: Thank you, it seems that your server does not reply.  Do you see the connection in your server logs when you connect via telnet?

Comment: When you telnet, can you share with us from the server the `lsof -i :80 -n` output?

Comment: @tukan The port is definitely open. If I do `nc -zv xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80` I get `Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port [tcp/http] succeeded!`

Comment: @K-att- `lsof -i :80 -n` doesn't show any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Docker opens exposed ports but they are not shown in UFW. Sorry I didn't mention Docker. I couldn't image it was related to it.

See this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/962012/ufw-not-blocking-incoming-traffic

Comment: Well that was key information...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Cloudflare Authenticated pulls instead then IP locking your server.

As you don't have a guarantee that the IPs stays the same you would also need to run a cronjob to fetch the IPs from cloudlfare and update your firewall. Also if I know your origin IP, I could still connect via my own cloudflare site its dns. Which would defeat the security measure of IP whitelisting pretty easy.

You can find information about authenticated pulls on the developer docs of Cloudflare:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/authenticated-origin-pull/